# How can to use javascript getTime() with php variable on it?

Tags: javascript, php, date

Im trying yo compare two dates, 1 is the date today second is the date based in my database(SQL Query). They told me to use `new Date()` but I'm confused how can I insert `php variable` there. So here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var today = new Date();
var expired = new Date(today);

function myDIV() {
  if (today >= expired) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor="#ff4d4d";
  }
}
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is whenever the second date is the same date as today, the div will change it's color. So I've tried using `>=` and `==` but no luck. Also I tried to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var today = new Date();
var expired = new Date($passport_expiration);

function myDIV() {
  if (today.getTime() >= expired.getTime()) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor="#ff4d4d";
  }
}
</script>
```

The format of the date is `mm/dd/Y`

Comment: what is the date format in $passpost_expiration, I mean epoch or yyyy-mm-dd ?

Comment: its mm/dd/Y sorry i will edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var today = new Date();
var expired = new Date("<?php echo $passport_expiration; ?> ");
alert(expired);
function myDIV() {
  if (today.getTime() >= expired.getTime()) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor="#ff4d4d";
  }
}
</script>
```

### Working copy

```
<?php 
#$passport_expiration = "07/12/2016";
$passport_expiration = "07/18/2016";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var today = new Date();
            var expired = new Date("<?php echo $passport_expiration; ?> ");
            alert(today.getTime() >= expired.getTime());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain this for me?

Comment: the result is always `TRUE` why is that?

Comment: I have updated the code, just to see the expired value. can you try it ? and please tell me what is the alert value

Comment: it says Fri Jul 15 2016 00:00:00 GMT + 0800 (China Standard Time). What is the meaning of that?

Comment: thanks for the code. but there is still a problem. when i set the `passport_expiration` lower than the date today, it gives me a `true` result but when I set the `passport_expiration` higher that the date today it gives me `false` result

Comment: and also, when i try to use the condition `==` it gives me `false` result

Comment: this code `<?php 
#$passport_expiration = "07/12/2016";
$passport_expiration = "07/18/2016";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var today = new Date();
            var expired = new Date("<?php echo $passport_expiration; ?> ");
            alert(today.getTime() >= expired.getTime());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>`
gives me a false result

Comment: I thought your requirement is to compare two dates. That why you are getting boolean date and time. What is your requirement then ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh dates are fun! There's a few things to think about.

- Is the PHP date the local date, or UTC?
- If you're using `getTime()` from JavaScript you're getting the number of milliseconds since 1970, so any date today won't **equal** your date from PHP which will convert to the time at midnight.
- Be careful with two digit years. Although you're probably safe for another 80 years or so.
- You said in the question you need to know when the days *match*. Could it just be when expired is less than right now? If not, you need to 'round down' the current time to the nearest day. I've broken it all apart so you can more easily go an look up the functions if you want.

```js
var testDate = '7/16/16';

var today = new Date();

var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
var day = today.getDate();
var fullYear = today.getFullYear() - 2000;

var todayString = month + '/' + day + '/' + fullYear;

console.log(todayString);
console.log(testDate);

console.log(todayString === testDate);
```

If it's all a bit daunting and you'll need to be working with JavaScript dates a lot, check out [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) (although it's relatively huge if that's a concern).

Comment: why it says that the today's date is `7/6/16` ?

Comment: `month = 7` and `day = 6` and ` fullyear = 16` is that right?

Comment: Yes, in this example the testDate is July the 6th, 2016. Note that JavaScript `getMonth()` is zero-based which is why I'm adding 1.

Comment: How can I make the `getDay()` same as the day today?

Comment: So sorry @aronpascua, I meant to have `getDate()` (which is the day of the month, `getDay()` is the day of the week). You must be getting confused. I will update the answer.

Comment: oh that is really helpful thank you for that mistake a gain more knowledge about date :)

Comment: Well I do try to make my mistakes as helpful as possible.